# How to customize a Queryset of a Field from a admin Inline that uses a pk of the primary form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Customizing a queryset of a form field in Django isn't a hard job. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391776/django-admin-inline-forms-limit-foreign-key-queryset-to-a-set-of-values)

But, assuming I have the following models:

```
#models.py

class Work(Model):
    name = models.CharfField(...)
    #some fields

class Gallery(Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work)

class Photo(Model):
   gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)

class StageOfWork(Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    #some fields
```

And an admin.py like this

```
#admin.py

class StageOfWorkAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StageOfWork
    form = StageOfWorkForm
    extra = 1

class WorkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EtapaObraAdmin]
```

I have this problem: when I edit a Work, exists many Form Inlines of StageOfWorks, these StageOfWorks inline forms have a Gallery selector.
I need to **customize de queryset** of this Galleries like this:

```
class StageOfWorkForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(StageOfWorkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
             self.fields['gallery'].queryset = Gallery.objects.filter(work__id=self.instance.work.id)
```

But this only works in the Forms who is editing forms. I need to get a work id in context of **init** method to do the right queryset anyway.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I have been able to do it is pass in the data you need into the instantiaton of the form class.

i.e., in your view:

```
def view(request):
    ...
    work = <whatever>
    form = StageOfWorkForm(work, request.POST)
    ...
```

Then, your form needs to the work object:

```
class StageOfWorkForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, work, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StageOfWorkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gallery'].queryset = work.gallery_set.all()
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this exact thing, but I did something similar. I used the Smart Selects Django plugin. This can be found here: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

I've use this to a filtered select in the admin, but it was in a regular model, not an inline, but it is quite possible that the plugin works in inlines too. I'd at least check it out.

Hailey

Comment: Wow! This is a sleek sleek project! It works flawlessly for normal forms and inlines too!